# Find records in one table which does not have a matching coulmn data existing in another table

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I need to query my database wherein one table's unique field is present in another table and using this i need to fetch only those records in the second table that don't have matching field in table row for a record in table one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM SECOND TABLE WHERE COLUMN_ID NOT IN(SELECT COLUMN_ID FROM FIRST TABLE);
```

Read more about NOT IN from:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Comment: I just had a doubt whether it'll work in SQLITE as  you gave me a link related to SQL

Comment: SQLite is a software library that implements a self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine. So it should process the SQL :-)

Comment: oh!!! i am not sure how i'll be able to iterate through the result that i'll get by using the query. I'll be needing a cursor for the result set, which i am not sure will be accessible by any means after executing the query!

Comment: You should be able to use resultset. Try some code and share it. I will try to help you with that.

Comment: Btw, so are you getting the desired rows from the SQL query?

Comment: sorry haven't tried yet... working on different aspect of the project. If i face any difficulties in implementing it i'll surely let you know.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:

        Finding records in one table not present in another table or 
        Difference between NOT IN, LEFT JOIN and NOT EXISTS.**

```
    SELECT a.i
FROM tableA   AS a
WHERE a.i NOT IN (SELECT b.j FROM tableB   AS b) OR a.i IS NULL
 ----------OR   There are at least three other ways to do this, which all are much more efficient!
    SELECT a.i FROM tableA AS a
        WHERE a.i NOT IN (SELECT b.j FROM tableB  AS b)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT a.i
        FROM tableA  AS a
        WHERE a.i IS NULL
     ----------OR   
        SELECT a.i
        FROM tableA  AS a
        LEFT JOIN tableB   AS b ON b.j = a.i
        WHERE b.j IS NULL
    ----------OR     
        SELECT a.i
        FROM tableA  AS a
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tableB   AS b WHERE b.j = a.i)
```