# Finding records in dba_users not in individual usertable

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following problem in Oracle 11g:

I have a table TBL_PERSON listing all users of my application and I need to find out all users of the database that are NOT mentioned in TBL_PERSON.

Count of tbl_person is 4207.

Count of dba_users/all_users is 4244. This means, that the difference of 37 users are system users not using the application.

So far so good. How do I identity the system users?

ID in table INT_PERSON is equal to USER_ID in dba_users. I expect a list of all users from dba_users table not listed in INT_PERSON. (37 rows)

I tried the following:

```
 SELECT * 
      FROM dba_users 
     WHERE USER_ID 
       NOT 
        IN (SELECT ID 
              FROM LCM.TBL_INT_PERSON);
```

The result is 3804 rows, also showing users from INT_PERSON -> not what I expected

Then tried:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM dba_users a 
 WHERE USER_ID 
   NOT 
    IN (SELECT ID 
          FROM LCM.TBL_INT_PERSON b 
          where b.id = a.User_id);
```

Which makes no difference.

Those post do not solve my problem:

[Find records in one table which does not have a matching coulmn data existing in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749168/find-records-in-one-table-which-does-not-have-a-matching-coulmn-data-existing-in)

[Select records from a table, which don't exist in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30779708/select-records-from-a-table-which-dont-exist-in-another-table?rq=1)

Or is it a secret of the dba_users table? Where is my mistake?

Comment: What does `which makes no difference` mean?  What results do you get?  Are there too few, too many, etc?  Be ***specific*** about the issues you are facing, with enough example data to demonstrate what you believe ***should*** be happening.

Comment: TBL_PERSON and INT_PERSON is different table. Or TBL_INT_PERSON is the table you are referring ?

Comment: Also, note that if one table has `{1,2,3,4,5}` and the other table has `{4,5,6,7}`, then there is a difference of 1 row, but there are 3 entries in the first table that are not in the second table.  That's why it is very important to gather example data to ***evidence*** your specific problem.  Perhaps manually check the two tables where the IDs are less than 10?  Then run your queries for just those IDs?  And manually verify that if the rows in each table have the same ID, they do actually relate to the same person.

Comment: @MatBailie... "makes no difference" means, that both queries I wrote give the same result of 3804 rows... I will try out what you wrote in your note about the IDs... and then come back...

Comment: @Shaili... sorry mixed up tablenames TBL_PERSON and INT_PERSON are the same table I am talking of. The very correct table is LCM.TBL_INT_PERSON with columns ID, NAME, VORNAME, FK_REF_ANREDE, FK_REF_TITLE, FK_REF_FUNKTION, ORACLE_USER, LASTUPDATE, LASTUSER, MITARBEITER_ID. ID is equal to USER_ID in dba-Users and MITARBEITER_ID and ORACLE_USER are equal to USERNAME in dba_users. Thanks

Comment: @MatBailie: you gave me the hint of checking for IDs and I did the following: checked one user for ID in both tables and found they are NOT equal. Checked the tables again for an equal column and found that username of dba_users and oracle_user of lcm.tbl_int_person are equal and then checked for one single user:

Comment: @MatBailie: thx for the hint to check IDs. Checked the tables for another equal column and found username of dba_users and oracle_user of lcm.tbl_int_person are equal. Example for 1 user: select username, user_id from dba_users where username='LCM'; result 1 row: username=LCM,user_id=7135. select id, oracle_user from lcm.tbl_int_person where oracle_user = 'LCM'; results 0 rows. So, user 'LCM' is not in table LCM.tbl_int_person. now I would expect from:
SELECT USERNAME FROM dba_users where USERNAME not in (select ORACLE_USER from lcm.tbl_int_person); 1 row but it did not! Result is 0 rows.

Comment: Check the datatypes, check of leading or trailing white space, check the collation.  And when posting code, use a ` to mark the code...

Comment: @MatBailie: Thx Mat, datatypes are varchar2 for both username in dba_users and oracle_user in lcm.tbl_int_person. What do you mean by "check of leading or trailing white space"? If you mean blanks, there are none. What do you mean by "check the collation"? If you mean (sort)order, order of username in dba_users is NOT equal to order of oracle_user in lcm.tbl_int_person. If this is my problem, what can I do next? Thx a lot.

Comment: What do these give you?  `SELECT * FROM dba_users WHERE username = 'LCM'` and then `SELECT * FROM lcm.tbl_int_person WHERE oracle_user = 'LCM'` and finally `SELECT * FROM dba_users WHERE username = 'LCM' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM lcm.tbl_int_person WHERE oracle_user = dba_users.username)`?  *(Slow replies because I'm at work.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I identity the system users?

First verify the count of application users.
This query should return all the ID of the application users, i.e. 4207
If not - you have other problem, than you describes.

```
select USER_ID from  dba_users
INTERSECT 
select ID from TBL_INT_PERSON;
```

Now show the system users

```
select USER_ID from  dba_users
MINUS
select ID from TBL_INT_PERSON;
```

This should return the IDs of the system user.

General note - simple subtraction of `count(*)` of two tables could be misleading, as there could be duplicated key and nulls in the tables. Using set operation as above is more secure.

Comment: GOT IT !!! Thanks to Marmite and halfer... The intersect and minus was it... Leant about it and that's just exactly what I wanted and needed. Well done, you saved me :-) ...
after changing user_id column to username column (which is the only equal criteria of the two tables) I received the correct result sets:
'select USERNAME from  dba_users
INTERSECT 
select ORACLE_USER from lcm.TBL_INT_PERSON;
resulted in the correct list of all users in both tables
'select USERNAME from  dba_users
MINUS
select ORACLE_USER from lcm.TBL_INT_PERSON;'
resulted in the correct set of only system users

Comment: @C.Poll glad to be able to share experiences;)